# Cannot change linestyle in Seaborn.FacetGrid

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to create a FacetGrid with full and dashed lines like [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44262695). Based on the code in the comment and on the [FacetGrid doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) this should work, however, I only get full lines, no dashes.

Could someone please help me out?

Min. working example:

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# toy data
x = [i for i in range(10)]*3
y = [0.5*i for i in range(10)]
y.extend([0.7*i for i in range(10)])
y.extend([0.3*i for i in range(10)])
mode = ["A" for i in range(10)]
mode.extend(["B" for i in range(10)])
mode.extend(["C" for i in range(10)])
method = ["X" for i in range(5)]
method.extend(["Y" for i in range(5)])
method = method*3
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : x, 'y' : y, 'mode' : mode, 'method' : method})

sns.set_context("paper")
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
blue = matplotlib.colors.hex2color('#5862f4')
pink = matplotlib.colors.hex2color('#e059c3')


kw = {'color': [pink, pink, blue], 'linestyle' : ["-","--","-"]}
p = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='method', hue='mode', sharey='row', margin_titles=True, hue_kws=kw)
p.map(sns.lineplot, 'x', 'y')
p.axes[0,0].set_xlim(0,10)
p.add_legend()

plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 7):

Seaborn `lineplot` overwrites the linestyle such as to use it with its `style` parameter. Here it seems you do not want to use the `style`. But also, there seems no reason to use `lineplot` at all. Hence a normal `plt.plot()` will work just fine.

```
kw = {'color': [pink, pink, blue], 'linestyle' : ["-","--","-"]}
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='method', hue='mode', sharey='row', margin_titles=True, hue_kws=kw)
g.map(plt.plot, 'x', 'y')
```

[image]

For completeness, here is how one would use the `style` argument for `lineplot` with a  `FacetGrid`.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='method', sharey='row', margin_titles=True)
g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, 'x', 'y', style="mode", style_order=list("ABC"))
```

[image]

Note that in order to guarantee the consistent mapping of the items of the `"mode"` column to styles, the style order needs to be set.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think your second version fits better but I would need to assign different colors to the lines and would like control over which mode has which line style and color. Is that possible?

Comment: The answer to the question is the first part. What exactly would be the reason not to use the proposed solution here? The second part is only to show the principle. I might remove that second part if it's too confusing.

Comment: The problem is that I have several data points per mode for each (x,y) coordinate due to multiple observations. plt.plot() simply draws one line for each observation, whereas sns.lineplot() draws a confidence interval (see first example [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html?highlight=lineplot#seaborn.lineplot)). I'd like the confidence interval, so I'll need to use sns.lineplot.

Comment: Okay, I found a working solution. Perhaps you could add it to your answer and then I'll accept it:

Comment: You need to set the `hue`, `dashes` and `palette` as well to take control over colors and styles, like so:  `p.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, 'x', 'y', style="mode", hue="mode", style_order=["A", "B", "C"], dashes=["",(2,2),""], palette={"A":pink, "B":pink, "C":blue})`

Comment: I rejected the edit, because I am currently not sure if `dashes` would mind the style order given. Also, there is no `hue_order` defined. If you verified that it does work for all cases (it would require to use a scrambled dataframe), you can provide your own answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "If you verified that it does work for all cases (it would require to use a scrambled dataframe)"? According to the doc, dashes works on the style variable, so I'd assume setting style_order should apply to the order of dashes, i.e. if the order is ABC, and the dashes are ["", (2,2), ""] then A and C have solid lines (which is the behaviour I have observed on my real data).